# Questions about pom.xml in Jenkins to run sonarQube through maven project

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, pom.xml

I'm trying to run sonarQube through Jenkins but I have some difficulties right now. When I build a new job, I use Maven Project and inside the configuration I have to give à pom.xml path but what does it correspond to ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should find in any jenkins job a post action for sonarqube analyse.

The pom.xml you mention is the pom.xml for your maven project, because sometimes you can put your parent pom.xml in a subdirectory and this is the way for helping jenkins to find it.

Comment: I don't really understand sorry, this pom.xml is the pom.xml belong to the git hub project I want to analyze ? Or somthing else ?

Comment: the pom.xml is your project parent pom, yes. Depdending of your project struture it can be anywhere, so you have to precise it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding Sonar Task to each project why not just configure Sonar at Global Level configuring the settings.xml for your maven configuration, just go to $HOME/someUser/.m2/settings.xml (if you don't have it created yet) with this content:

```
<settings>
    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- Optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
                <sonar.host.url>
                  http://myserver:9000
                </sonar.host.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
     </profiles>
</settings>
```

After you you have done that you will be able to run sonar in all the projects this way:

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar
 
# In some situation you may want to run sonar:sonar goal as a dedicated step. Be sure to use install as first step for multi-module projects
mvn clean install
mvn sonar:sonar
 
# Specify the version of sonar-maven-plugin instead of using the latest. See also 'How to Fix Version of Maven Plugin' below.
mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar
```

You may find more information in sonar official documentation:

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven

Comment: Hello, I have edited the settings.xml and added the core <settings>...</settings> for "root POM" and for "Goals and options" I added mvn clean  but same error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)used by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE
 at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.settings(DefaultMavenExec
 ... 21 more
ERROR: Echec à la lecture des POMs